# Feedback Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, nlp, bigdata, sentiment-analysis

We are trying to rank the products on the basis of score, score is calculated by analyzing the good or bad feedback about the product. After a lot of research and analysis we came up with this formula to compare and rank the products

**product score = Internal Probability + Positive Contribution - exp(Negative Contribution) - Sentiment score**

where

Internal Probability = ( # of Positive for product / Total feedback of a product )

Positive Contribution = (# of Positive for product / # of Positive for all Products )

Negative Contribution = (# of Negative for product / # of Negative for all Products )

sentiment score = Average(Negative Sentiment for product)

Range of Sentiment is from [0-1] where 1 shows very negative.

For large amount of data the average sentiment of all the product converges to the mean value, so it doesn't adds any value in the analysis. 
Any suggestions about we could improve this formula or use sentiment score to be more meaningful?